# Set Default Timestamp format till nanoseconds precision in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, amazon-aurora

When I am saving the retrieving the timestamp from aws aurora postgresql db, it is storing nanoseconds precision, but when I am querying from DB workbench, it's showing only milliseconds precision. Our requirement is to show in DB workbench the nanoseconds precision because we are saving a key in nano seconds part, that we need to see from DB. Please help me to show the timestamp column in nanoseconds precision format.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible because a [timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) has a resolution of 1 microsecond.

What you could do to work around this issue, is adding an extra integer field that stores the nanoseconds.

Comment: But why its giving the nano seconds precision while getting the values from hibernate, just not showing in sql console. Is it not at all possible to show in that nano seconds precision in sql console also?

Comment: No, there is no nano second in a timestamp in PostgreSQL, the resolution is just not there. It does have microseconds and that's the best a timestamp can do.
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 00:00:00.1234567890'; -- will loose the last 3 digits

Comment: Because Java [Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) has nanosecond precision? Are the last three digits something other then 0?